# Mysql | How to SELECT integer value from Mixed Integer String?

Tags: mysql, select

I have been searching now for hours.

Got a String like: `"_1_11_19_12_17_21_41_111_100_1"`

Now, I want the Output to be a single `1`

**When I try:**

```
"SELECT * FROM jobs_tb  WHERE position_id LIKE '%1%' "
```

This prints all most everything:

**I tried:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `jobs_tb`
WHERE (
`position_id` LIKE '%_1%'
)
OR (
`position_id` LIKE '%_1_%'
)
```

All most the same as the previous.

**How do you isolate a `1` when `1`s are mixed with other numbers?**

Any suggestion is highly welcomed

Comment: This task isn't really well-suited to SQL. Is there any way you could perform this task from your application code (PHP?)?

Comment: Also, if you expect to have to parse this data from within SQL frequently, I suggest storing the logic in a user function (`CREATE FUNCTION`) so you don't have to repeat the logic in other statements.

Comment: Any Idea how?... thx alot for the hint, please if ok, try to elaborate in an answer... thax again

Comment: @GolezTrol that's my interpretation of the question title, but the question body suggests he just wants to use it as a predicate in a `WHERE` clause (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that an underscore is a single character wildcard, just as the percent sign is a multicharacter wildcard, so if you want to match a literal underscore, you'll have to escape it. Also, the string can start or end with a '1', so you need to take that into account. A simple trick is to add extra underscores around the value to search in. Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `jobs_tb`
WHERE
  CONCAT('_', `position_id`, '_') LIKE '%\_1\_%'
```

Comment: Worked like VOODOO!... Thanks a million...(Accepted)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION PositionIdStringContains(positionIdText TEXT, digit TEXT) RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
    DECLARE digitStart TEXT;
    SET digitStart = CONCAT( digit, '\_%' );
    DECLARE digitEnd TEXT;
    SET digitEnd = CONCAT( '%\_', digit );
    DECLARE digitMid TEXT;
    SET digitMid = CONCAT( '%\_', digit, '\_%' );

    RETURN
        positionIdText LIKE digit OR
        positionIdText LIKE digitStart OR
        positionIdText LIKE digitMid OR
        positionIdText LIKE digitEnd
END;
```

Then use it in your `SELECT` statements like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    jobs_tb
WHERE
    PositionIdStringContains( position_id, '1' )
```

Comment: Thnks alot... though I get an Error: *[--#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 --]*

Comment: @UniversalGrasp that's probably because of my use of the `;` delimiter. You will need to configure your MySQL client accordingly. That's not something I can help you with.

Comment: Just to know, Will I have to be using this Function in Ever Query or the created function will automatically be stored in mySql memory forever?...Thanks again

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION` stores the function in the database permanently.